# A value for my HTML script read from a local text file

Tags: html

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:50px; border:5px solid black;">
<div id="progress-bar" style="width:67%;
   background-color:orange;
   height:50px;">
</div>
</div>
```

Where it says "style="width:67%" I want to have the 67% read from a local text file, for a script in progress. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - you can't read/write local text file on client's computer:

> JavaScript and the DOM provide the potential for malicious authors to deliver scripts to run on a client computer via the Web. Browser authors contain this risk using two restrictions. First, scripts run in a sandbox in which they can only perform Web-related actions, not general-purpose programming tasks like creating (or reading) files.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security

Answer (score 0):

What we are doing:

1. I suggest converting the text file's contents to JSON
2. Use Jquery.getJSON() function to parse the object
3. Use the width node to set the style tags width value

All together now:

```
Example data in file:
[{"date": "2016/01/05", "time": "18:46:00", "title": "ReadMe", "width": "67"}
```

1. ```
   jQuery.getJSON('textfiletoread.txt',function(data){
   // data is an array of objects
   $.each(data, function(){
      console.log(this.width); // log the width
    $('#progress-bar').css('width', this.width); //use the text files width
    });
   });
   ```